# Restsharp adds guid to body, how do I remove it?

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

My code is below, it is very simple.  I was trying to match a postman call and it came pretty close, but when I made the call in postman it looks different, specifically restsharp adds a guid around the body that I saw in fiddler.  The guide seems to break my calls, how do I remove it?

```
 string url = "https://url/api/";

                var client = new RestClient(url);

                client.AddDefaultHeader("x-ads-dev", "Key");
                var request = new RestRequest("telemetry", Method.Post);
               request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                request.AddParameter("application/json", datapoint, ParameterType.RequestBody);
                var response =  await client.PostAsync(request);
```

And here is what Fiddler shows:

```
POST http://url/api/telemetry HTTP/1.1
Host: api.adsprism.com
x-ads-dev: key
Accept: application/json, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, application/xml, text/xml
User-Agent: RestSharp/107.3.0.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Type: application/json; boundary="717cb9fd-684d-424e-bd0a-cf6b0bb11bac"
Content-Length: 398

--717cb9fd-684d-424e-bd0a-cf6b0bb11bac
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="application/json"

[{"entityID":2123,"locationID":33,"data":[{"dateTime":"2020-08-03 23:05:00","reading":0,"flags":0,"quality":15,"ignore":false},{"dateTime":"2020-09-27 03:10:00","reading":0,"flags":0,"quality":15,"ignore":false}]}]
--717cb9fd-684d-424e-bd0a-cf6b0bb11bac--
```

The --717cb9fd-684d-424e-bd0a-cf6b0bb11bac-- guid is not there in the fiddler postman request and it seems to be causing a bad request error from restsharp. So how do I make restsharp not generate it?

EDIT: Added postman fiddler to show the difference.

```
POST http://api.url/api/telemetry HTTP/1.1
x-ads-dev: key
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.0
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: 5f186e6d-cad0-482c-b7b8-a50559f24b87
Host: api.adsprism.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 513

[
    {
        "entityID": 2123,
        "locationID": 33,
        "data": [
            {
                "dateTime": "2020-08-03 23:05:00",
                "reading": 0,
                "flags": 0,
                "quality": 0,
                "ignore": true
            },
            {
                "dateTime": "2020-09-27 03:10:00",
                "reading": 0,
                "flags": 0,
                "quality": 0,
                "ignore": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Guid (boundary) is just a random separator to separate request post body from the headers. If you need POST, then you need this separator (will it be guid or any other char sequence). Could you please post "correct" request from postman for comparison?

Comment: I added the fiddler postman script that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the [docs](https://restsharp.dev/v107/#body-parameters) can help.

```
const string url = "https://url/api/";

var client = new RestClient(url);
client.AddDefaultHeader("x-ads-dev", "Key");

var request = new RestRequest("telemetry", Method.Post);
request.AddStringBody(datapoint, DataType.Json);
var response =  await client.PostAsync(request);
```